# how to hide data filter in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

anyone knows how to hide the data-filter for the list view upon page load ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>   
<body>
  <table class="table3">
    <tbody>
      <tr>

        <td>
          <a class="profileinfo1">
            <center><font size="5">8</font>
            </center>Service Called</a>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" class="friend">
    <li>Adam Kinkaid</li>
    <li>Matthew</li>
    <li>Owen</li>
    <li>Ryan</li>
    <li>William</li>
  </ul>

  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="transaction">

    <li data-role="list-divider"><font size="3">Cash Transaction</font>
    </li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>4th November 2015</b></u>
      <br>Service called: Plumbling
      <br>Service by: Timothy Tan
      <br>Payment made: $40</li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>14th June 2015</b></u>
      <br><b>Service called:</b>Computer Repair
      <br>Service by: Jonathan Tan Wee Hong
      <br>Payment made: $150</li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>12th January 2014</b></u>
      <br><b>Service called:</b>Lock Smithing
      <br>Service by: Adul Rashim
      <br>Payment made: $50</li>

    <li data-role="list-divider"><font size="3">Credit Card</font>
    </li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>18th July 2015</b></u>
      <br>Service called: LockSmithing
      <br>Service by: Adul Rashim
      <br>Payment made: $50
      <br>Card Used: Mastercard</li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>21th March 2014</b></u>
      <br>Service called: Computer Repair
      <br>Service by: Jonathan Tan Wee Hong
      <br>Payment made: $90
      <br>Card Used: Visacard</li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>15th November 2013</b></u>
      <br>Service called: Air-Con Repair
      <br>Service by: Hong Xin Chang
      <br>Payment made: $60
      <br>Card Used: Visacard</li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>10th May 2013</b></u>
      <br>Service called: Plumbling
      <br>Service by: Timothy Tan
      <br>Payment made: $200
      <br>Card Used: Mastercard</li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>12th January 2013</b></u>
      <br>Service called: Air-Con Repair
      <br>Service by: Hong Xin Chang
      <br>Payment made: $170
      <br>Card Used: Mastercard</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And another thing i would like to do is to hide the data filter upon clicking the class.For e.g:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".profileinfo3").click(function(){
        $(".friend").hide();
    });
});
```

[The search bar i wish to hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EueOn.png)

Comment: I really can't got your point .. what the meaning of hide data-filter??  remove it?? don't show it to user? keep its value and remove it or you don't need data-filter value anymore  or you need to change its value to empty?

Comment: i wish to hide the search bar dynamically

Comment: @JiewWei Does setting `data-filter` to `false` "hide" search bar ? Or is `data-filter` describing `ul.friend` element ? Tried calling `.hide()` within `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: no i want the data-filter to stay true but i want it to basically hide upon clicking a button and not showing it when the page load

Comment: tried .hide() , doesnt work for me , the search bar still stays there

Comment: _"tried .hide() , doesnt work for me , the search bar still stays there"_ Can describe "doesnt work" ?, create stacksnippets https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ to demonstrate ?

Comment: @JiewWei Is `html` that renders "search bar" at "The search bar i wish to hide" image link  included at Question ?

Comment: @JiewWei See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi sorry i dont know how to use code snippet , is there any other way to demostrate my problem?

Comment: Please clarify, you want to hide the <ul> tag OR the "searchbar"?..The first part of your question states you want to hide the <ul> tag and the last part says the search bar.......also do you want a create a button that when you click on it you see the <ul> or the searchbar?...beef up your question by being clear without question markes and we will try help

Comment: i wish to hide the searchbar

Comment: Fair enough :D....I am seeing a bunch of list tags in your edited answer....where is codes for your search bar/box like that you have in your image?...I am not seeing that....also... you want to create a special button that when clicked on you will see the search bar ONLY with no <ul> tags nor list?..

Comment: hi apparently im working with jquery mobile and the search box is created via data-filter="true" within the <ul> tag and i do not wish to create a special button . What i want is when i click on the "service called" , it will hide the search bar

Comment: okay...my answer is not a jquery solution but javascript (a couple of lines)..hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

here is  a snippet,when you click on "service called", the search box will hide as per your comment.

```js
function click(){
this.nextElementSibling.style.display="none";

}
document.getElementsByClassName('table3')[0].addEventListener('click',click,false)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>   
<body>
  <table class="table3">
    <tbody>
      <tr>

        <td>
          <a class="profileinfo1">
            <center><font size="5">8</font>
            </center>Service Called</a>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" class="friend">
    <li>Adam Kinkaid</li>
    <li>Matthew</li>
    <li>Owen</li>
    <li>Ryan</li>
    <li>William</li>
  </ul>

  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="transaction">

    <li data-role="list-divider"><font size="3">Cash Transaction</font>
    </li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>4th November 2015</b></u>
      <br>Service called: Plumbling
      <br>Service by: Timothy Tan
      <br>Payment made: $40</li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>14th June 2015</b></u>
      <br><b>Service called:</b>Computer Repair
      <br>Service by: Jonathan Tan Wee Hong
      <br>Payment made: $150</li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>12th January 2014</b></u>
      <br><b>Service called:</b>Lock Smithing
      <br>Service by: Adul Rashim
      <br>Payment made: $50</li>

    <li data-role="list-divider"><font size="3">Credit Card</font>
    </li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>18th July 2015</b></u>
      <br>Service called: LockSmithing
      <br>Service by: Adul Rashim
      <br>Payment made: $50
      <br>Card Used: Mastercard</li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>21th March 2014</b></u>
      <br>Service called: Computer Repair
      <br>Service by: Jonathan Tan Wee Hong
      <br>Payment made: $90
      <br>Card Used: Visacard</li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>15th November 2013</b></u>
      <br>Service called: Air-Con Repair
      <br>Service by: Hong Xin Chang
      <br>Payment made: $60
      <br>Card Used: Visacard</li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>10th May 2013</b></u>
      <br>Service called: Plumbling
      <br>Service by: Timothy Tan
      <br>Payment made: $200
      <br>Card Used: Mastercard</li>
    <li data-icon="info"><u><b>12th January 2013</b></u>
      <br>Service called: Air-Con Repair
      <br>Service by: Hong Xin Chang
      <br>Payment made: $170
      <br>Card Used: Mastercard</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```